# Biblatex-chicago: comma before closing quotation mark in author name

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, biblatex-chicago, quotation

I would like to add a nickname to an author, but when I do the below the closing quotation mark ends up before the comma. Is there some way to fix so that the bibliography entry would instead read as follows?

> "Archie,"

Preferably, the solution would be agnostic to if there will actually be another author listed after the nickname. But also more hacky/less robust solutions are much appreciated :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate,
            backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}{testing.bib}
  @article{smith,
    Title   = {Article title},
    Author  = {Smith, Archibald ``Archie'' and Anderson, Steven},
    Journal = {Journal title},
    Year    = {2014}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{testing}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{smith}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `biblatex`'s quotation command `\mkbibquote`. That command is usually able to move following punctuation into the quotation marks.

You may also want to load the `csquotes` package, though this does not make a difference for `\mkbibquote` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,
            backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{smith,
  title   = {Article title},
  author  = {Smith, Archibald \mkbibquote{Archie}
             and Anderson, Steven},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year    = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{smith}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith, Archibald “Archie,” and Steven Anderson. 2014. “Article title.” Journal title.]